# WCF Service reference intermittently breaking

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a service reference on my local dev environment to a WCF service hosted elswhere on our LAN, and it will just stop working at times with an error along the lines of "The document at the url was not recognized as a known document type."

A system reboot doesn't fix it, rather it starts working again on its own several minutes later.

Anyone else ever experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a network issue. When I get the problem, I just repair my LAN connection, clear my DNS cache and things work again.